# Swagger @ApiParam - How to specify default value for List using @ApiParam?

Tags: list, swagger

For String I able to specify default value and populate in swagger page, but not able to specify default
value and populate default value for List 
`@ApiParam(name = "languageCode", value = "Language Code", type = "String", example = "19", defaultValue = "19") @RequestParam(required = false) String languageCode,
@ApiParam(name = "countryList", value = "List of Countries", example = "["US","CA"]") @RequestParam(required = false) List countryList`

Your help is greatly appreciated